# Flash CS5 won't publish

Tags: flash, memory, export, publish, flash-cs5

I am trying to publish a project from Flash CS5 to an swf. The problem I'm facing is that the file will simply not publish. Flash will not throw any error messages, and just cancel the publish automatically. Anyone got any ideas??

Greatly appreciated!

Comment: which os are you using? already upgraded to lion?

Comment: see "file > publish settings" check the paths maybe you're looking in the wrong folder. also check the "COMPILER ERRORS" and "OUTPUT" tabs in the bottom pane see if you got anything there.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, and the output directories are correct. I should also mention though that my project is obese in file size, it's about 477 MB, I know this is large and flash is known to have problems at this size but I didn't have a choice, I couldn't learn how to do HTML5 or another alternative in the time I have until the due date, since it's a major work for my final year at school. If I can't get this to export then I don't have anything to hand in at all :(

Comment: Maybe try creating a simple project with nothing more than a trace statement and check that it will export?

Comment: Had the same problem. Solved it by increasing the java memory size in  `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS5\en_US\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\jvm.ini` from `-Xmx128m` to `-Xmx256m` but I don't know if that is any good solution.